# MSI GS60-GTX965 - Unable to get Bumblebee to run properly - Could not load GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my new laptop and while everything works great (save for the wifi card but that's a completely different matter) I'm having some trouble getting Bumblebee to run.

I followed the guide on [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Basic_Setup_for_13.10_and_later) thread to install it and everything seemed to be well but when I try to test it out running `optirun glxsheres` I get the following error message:

> [ 1465.129240] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver
>   [ 1465.129265] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

I know there are an awful lot of threads about this error and I went through several (specially [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424593/no-error-could-not-load-gpu-driver-cannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-coul) and 3 others but I lack the reputation to post the links xD) trying out the solutions posted there to no luck.

Some hardware info:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 1102
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13d9 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 1102
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f6000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting 
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 
    Capabilities: [900] #19
```

Not sure if it's okay or not but shouldn't the exact nvidia model be displayed there? GTX 965. 

Any idea/input/whatever that I could try? Thanks. Dunno what info might be needed so just ask.

Edit: Updating some info after my latest attempt to make everything run.

With `lspci -v | less`:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13d9 (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
```

I'm pretty sure that's not good but I installed Witched 2 through steam, set it to run using `primusrun` and I see the LED indicator on the laptop switch to indicate the dedicated VGA being in use and the game seems to run as smoothly as I can expect such a heavy game to run with everything set to ultra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: This is going to be painful...  As you're in Argentina and have no chat capabilities, I'll have to guide you through stuff from the other side of the planet.  My first request would be to uninstall Bumblebee so we can get the NVidia drivers correct!  Once all that is ok, you can then continue to install Bumblebee. (You've got an MSI-produced GTX 965, not an NVidia GTX 965)

Comment: thanks for the info!. 

I did some more experimenting last night but it was too late to add the results so I edited the original question now with a bit more info. That being said if you can put up with guiding me a bit on how to better install all this mess I would really appreciate it. 

I know the basics so installing/uninstalling stuff shouldn't be an issue. To start, should I uninstall just bumblebee or everything nvidia-related on my system as well?.

Comment: Start by clicking the sad little grey check-mark, turning it green and saying "Yes, this answer is valid".  :P  ;-)  If it works now, I wouldn't change anything further; you're one of the lucky few where it works from the first shot.  If you want to do mre then what you have, invest your time in [taking system backups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) You're definitely User type 4!  ;-)